# $Permission.CustomPermissionName doesn't work in VF page

Tags: visualforce, permissions, global-variables

Winter '15 brought new Global Variable $Permission. When I'm trying to use it on VF page as suggested in [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_permission.htm) $Permission.[customPermissionName], I get error:

> Error: Field [customPermissionName] does not exist. Check spelling

VF page version is 32. I also tried to add prefix 'can' but it didn't help.

Does anybody seeing the same behavior?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me. But I tried it an an org that has a namespace defined and got the same error you got unless I included the namespace prefix ("cve" in my case). So for me with a custom permission name of "Abcd" this didn't work:

```
{!$Permission.Abcd}
```

but this did:

```
{!$Permission.cve__Abcd}
```

Comment: Maybe specifying the default namespace `c__` would resolve this particular issue? {!$Permission.c__Abcd}

Comment: Thanks @Keith that works!@Mark, looks like specifying c__ doesn't work.